# React fails to include module with exported types and constants

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In one local NPM package I define a type and a constant:

```
export type Cat = {
  name: string,
  age: number
};

export const YEAR = 2024;
```

I created a React app with `npx create-react-app --template typescript react-app`. My App.tsx:

```
import { Cat, YEAR } from "share";

const myCat: Cat = {name: "Jerry", age: 4};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <p>My cat {myCat.name} is {myCat.age} years old in {YEAR}.</p>
  );
}
```

And the error:

```
ERROR in ../share/index.ts 3:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.runtime = require('/home/myUsername/ts-demo/react-app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| 
> export type Cat = {
|   name: string,
|   age: number
```

Removing the reference to the constant YEAR resolves the issue. However, I need to reference both types and constants from the share module, hence the impasse.

I have a TEMPORARY solution by separating the types and constants into share1 and share2, and including both packages into react-app. I don't understand why the error is occurring, and I don't understand why separating them into two separate modules fixes the errors. Any insight is appreciated.